# Significato di fru-fru

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, single-words, loan-words

Una mia amica mi ha detto che fru-fru può voler dire anche superficiale? È vero? Ho guardato nel dizionario Treccani ma non sono riuscito a capire i termini descritti lì dentro.

Comment: È vero! Hai già controllato nei sinonimi e contrari: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fru-fru_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/? In Sicilia è usato **scherzosamente** anche per dire *gay* ad un ragazzo o uomo nel senso di possedere un atteggiamento da omosessuale o più effeminato, frase di esempio "Sei diventato fru fru tutto d'un tratto?" oppure "Lui, tutto fru fru oramai, che può sapere delle donne!". Nonostante la fonte affidabile, curiosa mi è apparsa la pagina di wiki alla voce Wafer https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wafer_(biscotto)

Comment: Non prendere alla lettere la seguente in quanto non sicuro ma vado per uso e per sentito dire, esiste una scherzosa canzone in un film italiano, https://youtu.be/B9vQuOch74U?t=2m19s, nella quale si sente la parola fri-fri (frifri o fri fri) per indicare gay, omesessuale o volg., e mi scuso a priori, frocio. Nel sud mi capití di sentire "fri fri" ma mai usata **scherzosamente**.

Comment: Inoltre, e solo perché desidero togliermi un sassolino dalla scarpa, sperando che qualcuno possa confermare o meno, dal link http://dizionario.reverso.net/francese-definizioni/frifri sembra essere di provenienza francese, è vero?

Comment: Quali termini non hai capito, Jack? Forse sarebbe utile anche chiarire quelli, oltre che “fru fru”.

Comment: Ma quandi see fru-fru significa ragazzo effemminato o gay allora non c'entra niente "superficiale", giusto? Quindi questa amica si è per caso sbagliata nel darmi una spiegazione?

Comment: E poi ci sono I wafers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fru fru indicava nell'Ottocento le decorazioni utilizzate dalle donne come nastri e pizzi. Questo termine ha quindi preso il significato di superficiale e frivolo sia dal punto di vista dell'abbigliamento che dal punto di vista comportamentale della persona. Viene utilizzato anche per indicare una persona con caratteristiche dell'omosessuale stereotipato. In entrambi i casi viene utilizzata come connotazione dispregiativa.

> Tizio si comporta molto da fru fru
>
> Quel vestito sarebbe carino ma è troppo fru fru

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fru-fru/